# HaProxy LoadBalancing websocket

Tags: websocket, load-balancing, haproxy

We are using haproxy to load balance websocket connection to 4 node.js servers.

However we notice in prod unlink dev when we close the websocket (client refreshes pages or exits the browser etc)
**The websocket is dropped between the client and the LB but is not dropped between the LB and the node.**

Am i missing some kind of configuration?

I can't share the whole config file but here are some defaults:

```
defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option  log-health-checks
    retries 3
    option  redispatch
    option  httpclose
    maxconn 3000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000
    timeout tarpit 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
adding

`timeout http-keep-alive 300s`

`http-close-server`